# Map dataset to objects

Tags: c#, object, dictionary, dataset, dto

I have stored procedures that return couple of tables, and i want to map objects to the tables. Until now, i worked with type data set, and i want to stop working with them. I am looking for suggestions on how to do that, i thought about reflection, or iterate through each table in the data set and populate my object, or split the procedure to couple of procedures that each one of them return one table and iterate those tables with dataReader?

** Each object represent table in the data base.
** Each table in the procedure result contain data from specific table.

Thanks..

Comment: What programming language are you using? And is there a specific reason why you're not using an ORM to access your data? If you want to keep a class for each table you can implement the Active record pattern. Although I would prefer an ORM.

Comment: I Using c#, what do you mean ORM, like entity framework?

Comment: Yup like Entity Framework and NHibernate.

Answer (score 1):

There are a whole bunch of options for connecting database tables with C# code, as described in [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891734/best-free-library-in-net-to-handle-data-in-sql-server/3891740#3891740).

In short - no need to do all of this manually - though if you have existing classes you need to integrate, using manual mapping might be pragmatic this time around.